# logging will not write to file in python 2.7.4

Tags: python, file, logging

I cannot get the logging module to write to a file for the life of me and I have no idea what is the problem.

I am runnning

```
form = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(logfile='/home/gabriel/Developement/cl/cl.log',level=logging.DEBUG, format=form)
logging.debug("oh")
logging.info("oh!")
logging.warning("OH!")
logging.error("OH NO!")
```

I'm completely unsure of what's going on, the file is not created, nor is it written to. However, python does not raise an exception. I've tried running with python 2.7.4 and ipython. Please let me know what diagnostic steps I can take, I wish I could provide more information but I do not know what is relevant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `logfile` to `filename`, like so:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/gabriel/Developement/cl/cl.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=form)
```

You can see the keyword arguments taken by `basicConfig` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Comment: That did it. I don't know where I got 'logfile' from. Thanks a lot David :)